# Paypal IPN works, but doesn't update database. Unsure on how to debug

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

After ages I have finally managed to get my IPN from Paypal working. I found a code on GITHUB that provides a ipn.log which comes back with "Verified" or "Invalid".

Upon using the Paypal Sandbox, the transaction works and my ipn.log file updates telling me it was Verified.

However the code I've put in after this does not work and I'm at a complete loss on how to fix it!

Please see the form used on the buy page.. credit.php

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?=$person?>">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="mypaypal@email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="5000 Credits for <?=$person?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="5000 Credits">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?=$site[location]?>creditsdone.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?=$site[location]?>">
<input src="images/buy_button.gif" height="22" type="image" width="156" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal">

</form>
```

$person is the persons username taken from my database.

Please see my ipn.php page. I have blacked out the IPN verification system since this is working.

```
<?php
/* CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);
// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");
// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}
// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.
//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}
// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens)); */
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {


     if($mc_gross == "5.00"){ $turns="1000"; }//if($special==on){ $turns="1000"; } }

else{$turns="0";}

        $total=$payment_gross-$payment_fee;

        mysql_query("UPDATE $tab[user] SET Supcredits=Supcredits+$turns WHERE username='$custom'");
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tab[paypal] (tranid,amount,fee,user,datebought) VALUES ('$txn_id','$payment_gross','$payment_fee','$custom','$time');");
 echo "Turns given";
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.
    // assign posted variables to local variables
    //$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    //$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    //$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    //$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    //$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    //$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    //$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    //$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

    /*if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);

    }

} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);

    }

}*/
?>
```

I'm at a complete loss and my mind is a boggle! Please understand my php coding level is very basic!

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: You are using the variable `$mc_gross`, but you are not taking that from the `$_POST` data, I don't get how you are supposed to get the actual amount?

Comment: If I added `$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];` and then used `if($payment_amount == '5.00')` would that work?

Comment: That would make alot more sense, yes, PayPal sends PHP POST requests with the data you see in your IPN log.

Comment: Ok, i'll give it a try, thank you Jordy.

Comment: Oh and for debugging purposes, you can also use an IPN Simulator. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator

Comment: I changed it to this `$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
 $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
 $custom = $_POST['custom'];
 
  if($payment_amount == "5.00"){ $turns="5000"; }
  else{$turns="0";}

        mysql_query("UPDATE $tab[user] SET Supcredits=Supcredits+$turns WHERE username='$custom'");
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tab[paypal] (tranid,amount,fee,user,datebought) VALUES ('$txn_id','$payment_amount','$payment_fee','$custom','$time');");` but this didn't fix it after trying the transaction again :(

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll check out the debugger now.

Comment: No it still didn't give the "user" in this case me, any turns.

Comment: `UPDATE $tab[user] SET Supcredits=Supcredits+$turns` Shouldnt that supercredits be in quotes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72301/discussion-between-harry-sinfield-and-jordy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the variable `$mc_gross`, but you are not taking that from the `$_POST` data, I don't get how you are supposed to get the actual amount?

If you'd do $mc_gross = `$_POST['mc_gross'];` you'd actually have the price you're looking for!